# CodeIgniter Captcha Image not validate in Chrome while it is OK in Firefox

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, firefox

I have created a login form with captcha image using CI. It works perfect on Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. But I cannot succeed to login using Google Chrome (ver:  43.0.2357.81 m).

I have checked many times what comes as `captchaWord` in `$_SESSION` variable and what I post in `$_POST` variable. Everything looks OK.

If I disable captcha validation it also logs me in.

I have tried to see what is held in `captchaWord` key in `$_SESSION` variable. In order to do that I have created a link on which I click it gets me `$_SESSION['captchaWord']` value. It always brings me a new captcha word on Google Chrome but it is stable on Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer.

I don't know what the reason could be. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have call captcha image in controller, it is OK for Firefox and Internet Explorer. But Google Chrome and Yandex changes captchaWord value after sending it to view.

So I have decided to call captcha image using jQuery after page load is done. Then it is OK now for all browsers.

Weird.